# Append first column content and a prefix to end of line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to append a columns contents to the end of each line. For example, I have:

```
0,John L Doe,Street,City 

1,Jane L Doe,Street,City

2,John L Doe,Street,City

3,John L Doe,Street,City

4,Jane L Doe,Street,City

5,John L Doe,Street,City

6,John L Doe,Street,City

7,Jane L Doe,Street,City
```

Trying to append the first column deliminated by a comma to the end of each line including a character "I" to become:

```
0,John L Doe,Street,City I0

1,Jane L Doe,Street,City I1

2,John L Doe,Street,City I2

3,John L Doe,Street,City I3

4,Jane L Doe,Street,City I4

5,John L Doe,Street,City I5

6,John L Doe,Street,City I6

7,Jane L Doe,Street,City I7
```

Adding the "I" is easy enough to add with: `sed 's/$/I/'` file but I'm having issues with copying and appending the first columns contents

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+),.*$/& I\1/' file
0,John L Doe,Street,City I0
1,Jane L Doe,Street,City I1
2,John L Doe,Street,City I2
3,John L Doe,Street,City I3
4,Jane L Doe,Street,City I4
5,John L Doe,Street,City I5
6,John L Doe,Street,City I6
7,Jane L Doe,Street,City I7
```

The regex `([[:digit:]]+),.*$` matches from the first digit on the line to the end of the line.  The expression `([[:digit:]]+)` matches all the digits before the first comma and saves them in group 1.  The replacement text is `& I\1` where sed replaces `&` with the entire match and replaces `\1` with group 1.

The `-E` option tells sed to use Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) as opposed to the default Basic Regular Expressions (BRE).

Actually, the `$`, which matches at the end of a line, is not needed.  Because `sed` regexes are always leftmost-longest matches, our regex will always match to the end of the line anyway.  So, we could use the slightly simpler:

```
sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+),.*/& I\1/' file
```

#### Compatibility

The above should work on all modern `sed`.  For older GNU sed, replace `-E` with `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+),.*/& I\1/' file
```

Comment: Thank you! That was actually extremely helpful.

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/^\([^,]*\),.*/& I\1/' file` as the OP does say `Trying to append the first column deliminated by a comma`. Also notice `^` to anchor the regexp to the front of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

$ cat file.sh 
0,John L Doe,Street,City
1,Jane L Doe,Street,City
2,John L Doe,Street,City

$ cat example.sh 
while IFS=, read -r ID name street city; do
    printf '%s,%s,%s,%s, %s\n' "${ID}" "${name}" "${street}" "${city}" "I${ID}"
done < "$filelocation"

$ sh example.sh 
0,John L Doe,Street,City, I0
1,Jane L Doe,Street,City, I1
2,John L Doe,Street,City, I2



Another solution is:

$ cat file.sh 
0,John L Doe,Street,City
1,Jane L Doe,Street,City
2,John L Doe,Street,City

$ cat example.sh 
IFS='
'
for line in $(cat file.sh)
do
    echo ${line/%/ I${line%,*,*,*}}
done

$ sh example.sh 
0,John L Doe,Street,City I0
1,Jane L Doe,Street,City I1
2,John L Doe,Street,City I2
```

Comment: please see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice